# ERROR: No matching distribution found for segmentation-models-pytorch

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, kaggle, modulenotfounderror

I a trying to install PyTorch-segmentation-models in a Kaggle notebook. However, I'm facing an error .. Please help me resolve it...
Thanks!!

Command used:

```
!pip install -q -U segmentation-models-pytorch albumentations > /dev/null
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement segmentation-models-pytorch (from 
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for segmentation-models-pytorch
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot:]

Answer (score 0):

use `!pip install segmentation-models-pytorch==0.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to activate internet connection in the notebook.

Then I had issues with the pinned environment from https://www.kaggle.com/code/balraj98/deepglobe-land-cover-classification-deeplabv3, so I locally installed an older version, as so :

```
!pip install segmentation_models_pytorch==0.1.2
```